# How to find entries matching a specific string

Tags: mysql

I have more than 50000 records in my table with two columns (id and basic) looks like this

| ID | BASIC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX111XXX111 |
| 2 | XXXX22221111 |
| 3 | 111XXXXX2212 |
| 4 | 2X1X212X1X1X |
| 5 | X21X12X1X12X |

What I need is to display only records that consist of **5 "X"** that are not adjacent. for example, from the above records i need to get data like this

| ID | BASIC |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2X1X212X1X1X |
| 5 | X21X12X1X12X |

What query will suite to retrieve such record from my database.

Comment: "with no repetition of corresponding character."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret this as meaning that you want 5 Xs that are not adjacent.  I think this does what you want:

```
where concat(' ', col, ' ') regexp '([^X]+[X]){5}[^X]'
```

The `concat()` just takes care of the situation where the first or last character is an "X".

Comment: woow! it did what i wanted, but there are still repetition of 1 and 2, like this. "X1X1X1X1X111". how to adjust this to some thing like this "X1X1X1X1X112" because i need only two occurrence of characters like "11" or "22" or "XX" not "111","222","XXX".